# Specify DataSource in API with query in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am brand new to Pentaho reporting. I have a question regarding specifying DataSource. Is there a way to specify a DataSource using the API in Java with the query being specified in the .prpt file through Report Designer? 
I want to be able to create a report in the designer and preview it with a test datasource. But I want to specify a different connection/datasource when deployed through my webapp. So the only thing I want to override from the designer is which connection to use but use the same query that was specified in the Report Designer.